# how to load html and css first and the pictures, javascript etc later?

Tags: javascript, html

i have recently built a site, which pull youtube images, videos and i am also using few javascript external file, as a result, page loads very slow. How do i make page load faster ?

Comment: Here are a few basic tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005827/what-can-i-do-to-decrease-load-times-of-html-pages

Comment: Are you looking for `onload`?

Answer (score 0):

There may be several reasons of slow loading.
-It may be the problem of your server. Please check your server. (You can test your other site on this server if you have)
-It may you are using very big size of images. Or may be a lot of images?
-You have not mentioned any code. More detail can be told by checking the code that you have used on this page.
-May be the internet connection problem.