# how to arrange the sequence of js and css files in webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

Should I put **.js** in front of **.css**, or **.css** in front of **.js** files? Which is better? I'm working on a html5 project with jquery.

Comment: Some people believe it's better to include CSS files before javascript. Benchmark show that currently there's no much difference. Here is an interesting discussion with some benchmarks:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271276/is-the-recommendation-to-include-css-before-javascript-invalid

Comment: This post will help you much http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271276/is-the-recommendation-to-include-css-before-javascript-invalid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no better way. As long as they are all in the header there is no difference in their order unless they depend on each other.

EDIT: The above is true in most simple cases.

Ideally, you should put all of your CSS styles in the `HEAD` element and all of your `SCRIPT` elements in the order of dependence at the end of the `BODY` element (directly before the ending `</body>`).

Different orders can make *some* difference in newer **desktop** browsers. In mobile browsers, speculative parsing is not available, so the browser waits for requests of scripts before any other loading is performed.

tl;dr - It doesn't really matter as the differences are trivial, especially if your frontend has heavy JavaScript dependence.

Answer (score 1):

A general rule is to put stylesheets (.css) at the top and scripts (.js) at the bottom.  But be careful, you might not be able to put all your scripts at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://headjs.com/ which will optimize loading of JS and CSS.  http://requirejs.org/ is also a good framework for handling this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) which makes decisions like this for you based on best practices formulated by top front-end developers over the last 4 years. The code is really well commented and the documentation is excellent so you can easily learn more about the thinking which informed the various decisions, but if you just want to get on with building your page, safe in the knowledge that your foundation is sound, you can.