# css style switcher for bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to implement a style switcher according to https://www.inetsolution.com/blog/march-2010/css-style-switcher-a-quick-and-dirty-how-to .
but as soon as i add a title="" to the css link, the css file won't get loaded on the page an the styles fall back to default bootstrap.
my external css files are added at the bottom of the body. the order is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
        }
    </style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-alternate-styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fontello-xxxxxxxx/css/fontello.css">
```

is there something i miss?

Comment: what errors do you get? can you provide some jsfiddle?

Comment: not sure if i did my first fiddle correctly so you can get relevant information out of it... see here: https://jsfiddle.net/pigsound/em37bdjj/11/

Comment: @pigsound see my answer, I'm very well acquainted with this particular code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably did everything right (except one thing, see below*), the code that's in the article is using curly quotes ‘’ “” when it should be using straight quotes '' "".

> ```
> <a href=”#” onclick=”setActiveStyleSheet(‘default’); return false;”>Change style to default</a>
> <a href=”#” onclick=”setActiveStyleSheet(‘alternate’); return false;”>Change style to alternate</a>
> ```

So if you copied and pasted this part, it won't be parse correctly. This is the correct way with straight quotes:

> ```
>  <a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('default'); return false;">Change style to default</a>
>  <a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('alternate'); return false;">Change style to alternate</a>
> ```

Review this [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/vUAyNAQlMvR4QiJFHOd0/) instead of the Snippet. The Snippet won't work because of the multiple stylesheets involved.

**SNIPPET** (Not Functional, review [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/vUAyNAQlMvR4QiJFHOd0/) instead.)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='default.css' title='default' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='alt.css' title='alt' rel='alternate stylesheet'>
        <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <p>TEST</p>
      </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='styleSwitcher.js'></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

`*` I noticed you said:

> ...my external css files are added at the bottom of the body...

You should always place `<link>`s inside the `<head>`. Most often, JavaScript/jQuery needs the actual DOM to be loaded before it can do anything. So it's important in most situations to make sure your styling (`<link>` and `<style>`) go first and inside the `<head>`.

For `<script>`, it's best to place them at the bottom of `<body>` just before the closing tag `</body>`. See the Snippet and [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/vUAyNAQlMvR4QiJFHOd0/) for example of `<link>`, `<style>`, and `<script>` layout.

Comment: so you mean there are too many stylesheets involved in my html code?
when i reload the page, for 1 sec the correct css is visible, but then it seems to switch off and the default css shows.
i tried to put all css up into the head, but the error still comes up - as soon as the css-link gets a title="", it won't be recognised. when the css is included in the head instead of at the bottom of the body, it directly shows the default bootstrap css without showing the custom css for not even 1 sec.
i reviewed the plunker you added. it seems to work in chrome, but not in firefox.

Comment: I Tested it with Chrome, Firefox, and Edge on PC. On Mac I tested on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. No problems at all. Are you using WordPress, Drupal, Joomla, or some other CMS? It's common practice to place all styles in the head especially links, so no I'm not saying you have too many stylesheets. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18449119/2813224

Comment: sorry, i was unprecise: i opened your plunker on pc in firefox and chrome and saw that in firefox it didn't work.
thanks for your help and advice, i'll go on trying.

Comment: Do you know how to use firebug? F12 then click the console tab and see the errors? There is something in your environment that's inhibiting simple functions or it's a simple typo. `styleSwitcher.js` is a cross-browser script that's been around for years, it's very solid and basic (basic when you see each function that is.)