# Linking to external stylesheet and javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to link my HTML home page to an external css stylesheet and an external javascript(.js) file. For whatever reason depending on which order I list them in the HTML file, only one of them will work. I used a simple alert box in the Javascript file to test if it is working and it only does when the javascript file is linked first. Here is my work...(I am an HTML noob by the way also)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8 /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="trinity.css" />
<Script src="churchJavaScript.js"></script>
<title>Trinity Temple</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="CompleteWrapper">

    <header id="headerSection">
        <h1> Trinity Temple</h1>
        <h3> &nbsp;&nbsp;And I sent messengers unto them, saying, I am         doing a great work, so that I cannot come down:  </br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;why should the work cease, whilst I leave it, and come     down to you?  Nehemiah 6:3 </h3> 
    </header> 

<nav id="navSection">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li><a href="serviceInformation.html">Service Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="directory.html">Directory</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section id="sectionSection">
    <h3> Welcome to Trinity Temple Church of God In Christ! </h3></br>
    <hr width = 75% size= "1" color="#b20000" />
    testing tolaslksdflksdflksdflkslkdslkjdslksfdlkdslkdslk</br>
    testing tolaslksdflksdflksdflkslkdslkjdslksfdlkdslkdslk</br>
    testing tolaslksdflksdflksdflkslkdslkjdslksfdlkdslkdslk</br>
    testing tolaslksdflksdflksdflkslksadfsadfsdafsdadslkjdslksfdlkdslkdslk</br>
    testing tolaslksdflksdflksdflkslkdslkjdslksfdlkdslkdslk</br>
    testing tolaslksdflksdflksdflkslkdslkddddddjdslksfdlkdslkdslk</br>
    testing tolaslksdflksdflksdflkslkdslkjdslksfdlkdslkdslk</br>
</section>

<aside id="asideSection">
</aside>

<footer id="footerSection" >
    2900 Josephine St. </br>
    Denver, CO 80207
</footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the javascript code in the external file...

```
window.addEventListener("load", todaysDate, false);
function todaysDate(){
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();

var completeDate = document.getElementById("footerSection");
footerSection.innerHMTL = "Today's Date: " +completeDate;
alert(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);

}
window.addEventListener("load", todaysDate, false);
```

Also, here is the code in the service information html doc...

```
<!doctype html>

<html >
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="churchJavaScript.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="trinity.css"/>
<title> Service Information</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="CompleteWrapper">
<header id="headerSection">

    <h1> Trinity Temple</h1>
    <h3> &nbsp;&nbsp;And I sent messengers unto them, saying, I am doing a     great work, so that I cannot come down:  </br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;why should the work cease, whilst I leave it, and come down to      you?  Nehemiah 6:3 </h3> 
</header> 

<nav id="navSection">
<ul>

    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>Service Information</li>
    <li><a href="aboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="directory.html">Directory</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

<section id="sectionSection">
<h2> Service Information </h2></br>
<hr width = 75% size= "1" color="#b20000" />
<h3>Sunday</br></h3>
Sunday School: Sunday 9am - 10:30am </br>
Sunday Service: Sunday 10:30 - 1:00pm</br>
</br>
<h3>Wednesday</br></h3>
Bible Study: 6:30pm - 8:30pm
</br>





</section>

<aside id="asideSection">
</aside>

<footer id="footerSection" >

2900 Josephine St. </br>
Denver, CO 80207
</footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this inside your `<head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="churchJavaScript.js"></script>
<link href="trinity.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Make sure **trinity.css**, **churchJavaScript.js** and your **html file** are in the same folder.

It's slightly better for performance on desktop websites to put the js before the css. [Read why here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271276/is-the-recommendation-to-include-css-before-javascript-invalid).

Comment: Made the changes, I noticed however that when I navigate to the service information page then the javascript runs but it will not run on any other page...any suggestions?

Comment: Your javascript is dodgy. You'd adding the `window.load` event twice which will make the `todaysDate` function run twice. More importantly, `footerSection.innerHTML` will result in an error as `footerSection` does not exist