# Datepicker and Image Slider conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

Could you please help me sort the issue out. 
After inserting datepicker code, now my imageslider does not appear. All i see is a white space. 
I think some javascripts are conflicting ? 
But cannot find out which one.

Please help me.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"  media="all">


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.4.2.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.jquery.min.1.3.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.onload = function(){
     new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
       target:"inputField",
       dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
    });

     new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField2",
       dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
   });
   };
   </script>



    <script src="js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="layerslider/jQuery/jquery-easing-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="layerslider/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


   <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
    skinsPath : 'layerslider/skins/',
    skin : 'florida',
    navStartStop        : false,
    thumbnailNavigation : 'hover',
    hoverPrevNext : true,
   responsive : true,
   responsiveUnder : 1200,
    thumbnailNavigation : false,
   sublayerContainer : 1200
   });
   });      
   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/doubletaptogo.js" ></script>
   <script defer src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, write some neat code and check it.

```
script type="text/javascript" src="js/doubletaptogo.js" ></script>
```

Should be:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/doubletaptogo.js" ></script>
```

Then, when i look at your HTML, it looks like you are loading jQuery twice? And always load your stylesheets first, you can read this topic why: [Is the recommendation to include CSS before JavaScript invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271276/is-the-recommendation-to-include-css-before-javascript-invalid)

Also, check if the plugins you are using, are compatible with jQuery 1.4.2 it is possible they are using some things that jQuery 1.4.2 doesn't offer.

Comment: Hi Veritas87, Thank you for your reply. But I am very new to this sort of stuff. Could I please show you the whole website and if you could please check it for me ? I will appreciate it. Many thanks once again.