# Bootstrap Glyphicons are showing only after page is fully loaded

Tags: performance, glyphicons

> I already posted my problem at my `phpBB` community [here](http://www.klayz.com/community/).

As you can see, the Glyphicons are shown after all the others elements are loaded in the page. **Why?**

Is there a way I can `cache` them in order to show them as fast as possible? 
**What do you think?**

Let me know! And thanks in advance!

This is the code that I'm currently using to call the icons:

`@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");`

If you need to know what I have inside my `public_html/community/.htaccess` please let me know and I'll post it!

Comment: I think you are experiencing a racing condition. http://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/race-condition

Comment: Yeah, nice comment! But... don't you have some suggestions in order to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is really important to  load the css before anything else, you should use require.js

Please read this article. 
http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html

And

[Is the recommendation to include CSS before JavaScript invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271276/is-the-recommendation-to-include-css-before-javascript-invalid)

Comment: Ok, I changed the load order including first all the required CSS and then the Js files. It is a little bit fast now. Thank you for your help, Alvaro Joao.

Comment: np! :) if this answer solved the issue mark it as correct answer.@GlaucoZega